# How to refresh element in angular 8 without page reload?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

i'm updating database column with a button click, and i want to change the button after click. How can i achieve that without refreshing the page?

Below is my code. and it works fine only if i refresh the page.

```
    <button *ngIf="solved==1"  class="btn btn-success float-right">Marked</button>
    <button *ngIf="solved==0" (click)="mark()" class="btn btn-warning float-right">Mark </button>
```

Comment: just call the ngOnInit function after you added to the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the `ngOnInit()` once you are done with the processing logic of `mark()`

```
mark() {
  ...
  this.ngOnInit();
}
```

Also, note that *trying* to route back to the same page will not work as Angular will not re-route you to the same page without explicitly telling it to.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I was stumped because AngularJS seems to do this without it, but wasn't working with Angular.